Unable to identify and click svg tag elements while running on pipeline
My selenium automation script is not able to identify and click a particular element when it is running on server(pipeline) but the same is working fine while running on local.
The element is given below:
<svg x="75%" y="5" class="svg-anchor" data-control="page-add-controls">

I had used many locators like Xpath, CSS, linkText but no luck on all.
Xpath used :
//*[@data-control='page-add-controls']
Noticed this with only svg tag attributes.

What's the error stack trace ?

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: {"status":60,"value":"[object SVGSVGElement] has no size and location"}
